# convert ng-pluralize directive into a Javascript function.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I was going through [ngPluralize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPluralize) directive example which is exactly what I needed, but I was wondering if its possible to convert this into a Javascript function in an ng factory service.

The function in ng service would just remove the logic from html and reduce number of lines of code if I had a service where I can pass string and the service can check if the string is plural or singular.

here is what I want to convert into a function in ng service:

```
 <ng-pluralize count="numberOfCars" 
      when="{'0':'0 Cars',
             '1': '1 Car',
             '2': '2 Cars',
             'other': '{} Cars'
      }">
```

Comment: after seeing the directive's link function, yes you can. use the inputs that are from the element as a parameter, i think.

Comment: do you have an example in a form of jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: ok, see example below -- you need to check for bugs, because i didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved my question with few lines.

here is the html:

```
 <ng-pluralize count="numberOfCars" when="pluralize('')"></ng-pluralize>
```

here is the angularjs solution:

```
 $scope.pluralize =  function() {

  return{
    '0': ' No cars',
    '1': ' car',
    'other': '{}'+' cars'
  };
};
```

Answer (score -2):

pkkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/b1bFqZdoGVNyC5KOCkJp?p=preview

you need to check for bugs, because i didn't...

```
  angular.module("ng").factory("myplural", function($interpolate,$locale){

        return _service;
        // whens is an object
        function _service(scope,count,when) {
            var numberExp = count,
                  whenExp = when, 
                  whens = angular.isObject(when) ? when : {},
                  whensExpFns = {},
                  startSymbol = $interpolate.startSymbol(),
                  endSymbol = $interpolate.endSymbol(),
                  isWhen = /^when(Minus)?(.+)$/;

            var BRACE = /{}/g;

            angular.forEach(whens, function(expression, key) {
              whensExpFns[key] =
                $interpolate(expression.replace(BRACE, startSymbol + numberExp + endSymbol));
            });

            function pluralize() {
                value = numberExp;
                //if explicit number rule such as 1, 2, 3... is defined, just use it. Otherwise,
                //check it against pluralization rules in $locale service
                if (value in whens) {
                    return whensExpFns[value](scope);
                }

                return '';
            }

            return pluralize();
        }

    }).run(function($rootScope, myplural){
        $rootScope.myplural = myplural;
    });
```

Comment: is there any documentation on this?

Comment: this is the official docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPluralize

Comment: for the code, you can open angular.js, http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js, i think the current ngPluralize still has a bug, because the 'other' from their example didn't work, so i have to do something from the example above

Comment: i remove the 'offset', you don't need it and its buggy